# What is the easiest way to test method which have URLConnection

Tags: testing, mocking, spock

What is the easiest way to test method which have URLConnection? The problem is, I need to get an InputStream from this URLConnection. So I have no idea how to mock this classes due URL is final class.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create an URL on a file, which is part of your test :

```
URL testUrl = new URL("file:src/test/resources/my.test.properties");
def connection = testURL.openConnection()
```

Comment: not in a unit test. It's something you could do in an integration test, with a real server. A file URL is a real object, with a "real connection". You'll test nothing more with a "real connection", same behavior, same API